# How to handle JWT expiration in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-jwt

I use slim-jwt-auth on the server side. I don't find a good way to handle token expiration in angular.

My current strategy:

I use a canActivate guard to check the token before accessing a route. Check mean:
 - check if token is valid (server)
 - check expiration date with angular2-jwt helpers (client)

If token has a expiration time < 1 day I refresh the token.

Is it possible to start this steps on every http request and not only when accessing routes? For example when the user hanging around on the route a long time?

One method could be a time interval to check. But maybe there are better solutions?

Comment: You can use a BaseService where you provide a method for http errors, if you get a 401 you can refresh the token a retry the previous request.

Comment: is it possible to implment this service as middleware for all http requests?

Comment: Well the easiest way is to extend from a BaseService that will handle all the http requests, you just provide methods for get, post, put, delete and the handler for errors.
If you want something more like a middleware you should create something that accepts handlers and stack them and then process all of them before or after running the http request.

Comment: this could give you some solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428184/angular2-how-to-best-handle-expired-authentication-token

Comment: for me an easy solution can be a "auto sign out" when the token has expired: https://blog.khophi.co/auto-sign-client-expire-jwt-angular/